# Why did "gradlew assembleDebug" produce more than one apk?

Tags: android, apk, gradlew

I am working on Mac and I used to use `./gradlew assembleDebug` in command line to build my Android app's `app-debug.apk` for internal distribution. But this time it turned out to be 4 files

```
app-arm64-v8a-debug.apk
app-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
app-x86_64-debug.apk
app-x86-debug.apk
```

I remember a few weeks ago this same command was producing a single file `app-debug.apk`. Does anyone know how to build one single `app-debug.apk` as before?

Comment: They are different in CPU architectures, shown by the name. You should have some basic knowledge among them: x86 vs arm, 32 vs 64, etc.

Comment: Sorry about not asking my question clearly. @GenoChen Yes I know they are for different architectures but I don't really care about that. What I am looking for is the single `app-debug.apk` as I had before. I don't want to post 4 download links and let the users try out one by one to find out which one fits their device. I revised my question a bit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

`app/build.gradle`

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
```